# django - не может отобразить изображение из класса PostDetailView

Tags: python, django

на главная страница, изображения отображаются правильно, но когда я открываю `Post_detail`, изображение не отображается.

**Post_detail.html**

```
<img class="rounded image" src="{{ post.image.url }}">
```

**homeApp URL**

```
    from django.urls import path
    from .views import *

    urlpatterns = [
        path('', index, name='index'),
        path("post/<int:pk>/", PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail')


    ]
```

**Views**:

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'post_detail.html'
```

**URL**

```
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path, include

    from django.conf import settings
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('', include('home.urls'))
    ] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    if settings.DEBUG:
        urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**Models**

```
    from django.db import models


    class Post(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=140, unique=True)
        content = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

        image = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts/', default='default.jpg')

        def __str__(self):
            return self.title
[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]
```

**Settings**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]

MEDIA_URL = "static/media/"

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/media')
```

**Admin**

```
from django.contrib import admin from .models import *
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

admin.site.register(Post)


def image_tag(self):
    return mark_safe('<img src="%s"/>' % self.image.url)


image_tag.allow_tags = True
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: попробуйте `<img src="{{MEDIA_URL}}{{post.image}}">`

Comment: Not Found: /post/7/static/media/default.jpg

Comment: намудрили с urls - .../static/media/...jpg - тут либо одно, либо другое. в админке все хорошо? добавьте в модель: def image_tag(self): return mark_safe('<img src="%s"/>' % self.image.url) image_tag.allow_tags = True, чтобы было понятно уже в админке

Comment: на данный момент перестало вообще что либо отоброжаться и почему вам кажеться, что я замудрил. Если есть идеи как облегчитть, то поделитесь пожалуйста.

Comment: у вас settings.DEBUG True или False? судя по вашим настройкам url картинки у вас должен быть что-то вроде: /media/posts/default.jpg  (MEDIA_URL == /media/ и image.url == posts/default.jpg) проверьте хорошо settings.py, urls.py...и что у вас в админке показывает?

Comment: DEBUG=True
и я добавил дополонительную информацию, можете посмотреть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

model

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=140, unique=True)
    content = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='posts/') # remove default

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title)

    def image_tag(self):
        return mark_safe('<img src="%s"/>' % self.image.url)

    image_tag.allow_tags = True
```

admin

```
@admin.register(Post)
class Post_Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('id', 'image_tag')
    fieldsets = [
    (None, {
        'fields': ['title', 'content', 'image',]
    }),
    ('extra', {
        'classes': ('collapse',),
        'fields': ['image_tag']
    }),
    ('Поля-для-чтения', {
        'classes': ('collapse',),
        'fields': ['id']
        }),
]
```

ну, и раз DEBUG=True...что-то типа этого:

settings

```
if not DEBUG:
    # вариант, когда статика раздается apache/nginx
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
    MEDIA_URL = "/static/media/"
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
else:
    # вариант development'a
    STATICFILES_DIRS = [r'd:\Python\card2\static']
    STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    MEDIA_URL = "/static/media/" # по мне, static - лучше в отдельную папку, media - тоже в  отдельную, на одном уровне
```

*и вообще, не мучайтесь c DEBUG=True - делайте сразу staging*